# express route req.app is undefined

Tags: node.js, express, request

After reading [this part](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.app) and not getting this to work, I created this small test code.

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()

app.set('fruit', 'banana')

app.post('/api/v1/test', function (req, res) {
    // this should work
    const fruit = req.app.get('fruit')

    console.log(`req keys: ${JSON.stringify(Object.keys(req))}`)
    console.log(`req.app: ${JSON.stringify(req.app)}`)
    console.log(`req.params: ${JSON.stringify(req.params)}`)
    console.log(`fruit: ${fruit}`)
    return res.send('hello world')
})

app.listen(6002, () => console.log('listening on 6002'))
```

After sending an http request to this route the console is printing:

```
listening on 6002
req keys:
["_readableState","readable","domain","_events","_eventsCount","_maxListeners","socket","connection","httpVersionMajor","httpVersionMinor","httpVersion","complete","headers","rawHeaders","trailers","rawTrailers","upgrade","url","method","statusCode","statusMessage","client","_consuming","_dumped","next","baseUrl","originalUrl","_parsedUrl","params","query","res","route"]
req.app: undefined
req.params: {}
fruit: undefined
```

the question is why `req.app` is undefined when it is clearly should hold a reference to the app so i can use that to `req.app.get` settings

Comment: What's the specific issue you are having? Your question is a bit vague on that.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: the question is why `req.app` is undefined when it is clearly should hold a reference to the app so i can use that to `req.app.get` settings

Comment: Somewhat related, `req.app` is a function that has properties assigned to it. I got stuck on this for a minute when I inspected it and saw that it was a function.